# MySQL query with self-join scans millions of rows

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, self-join

I have an application to work on employee shifts for factories. I have a SQL query to find out if shifts have conflicts: if you have a shift 08:00-16:00 and I assign another shift 09:00-17:00 on the same day, this is a conflict because you can't be in both shifts at the same time. But a shift at 16:00-17:00 should not create a conflict, so the start and end time is important. Also, shifts can come from the previous day.

```
SELECT 
  `shifts`.`id` 
FROM 
  `shifts` 
  INNER JOIN `shifts` `shifts_2` ON `shifts_2`.`employee_id` = `shifts`.`employee_id` 
  AND `shifts_2`.`start_at` < '2023-03-01 00:00:00' 
  AND `shifts_2`.`start_at` < `shifts`.`end_at` 
  AND `shifts_2`.`end_at` > '2023-01-31 23:59:00' 
  AND `shifts_2`.`end_at` > `shifts`.`start_at` 
  AND `shifts_2`.`id` != `shifts`.`id` 
WHERE 
  `shifts`.`id` IN (22258796, 22258797);
```

I've simplified the number of shift IDs in the last line for readability, but since this list is dynamic I've seen queries using 6k IDs there. When this happens, this query scans millions of rows, thus taking >10s just to return the data.

```
CREATE TABLE `shifts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_shifts_on_employee_id` (`employee_id`),
  KEY `index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at` (`employee_id`,`start_at`,`end_at`),
  KEY `index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end` (`employee_id`,`id`,`start_at`,`end_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_03a7d0ca25` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32677939 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

If I run an `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` for the query, this is what I get:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "62.36"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "shifts",
          "access_type": "range",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY",
            "index_shifts_on_employee_id",
            "index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at",
            "index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "8",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 2,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 2,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "2.41",
            "eval_cost": "0.40",
            "prefix_cost": "2.81",
            "data_read_per_join": "2K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "employee_id",
            "start_at",
            "end_at"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`shifts`.`id` in (22258796,22258797))"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "shifts_2",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "index_shifts_on_employee_id",
            "index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at",
            "index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end"
          ],
          "key": "index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "employee_id"
          ],
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "shifts.employee_id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 141,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 3,
          "filtered": "1.11",
          "using_index": true,
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "3.02",
            "eval_cost": "0.63",
            "prefix_cost": "62.36",
            "data_read_per_join": "3K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "employee_id",
            "start_at",
            "end_at"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "((`shifts_2`.`start_at` < '2023-03-01 00:00:00') and (`shifts_2`.`start_at` < `shifts`.`end_at`) and (`shifts_2`.`end_at` > '2023-01-31 23:59:00') and (`shifts_2`.`end_at` > `shifts`.`start_at`) and (`shifts_2`.`id` <> `shifts`.`id`))"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                      | key                                                    | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shifts   | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end,index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at,index_shiftsshifts_on_employee_id | PRIMARY                                                | 8       | NULL               |    2 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shifts_2 | NULL       | ref   | index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end,index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at,index_shiftsshifts_on_employee_id         | index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at | 4       | shifts.employee_id | 8626 |     1.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

If I limit the `shifts_2` table by ID I get better results apparently, but I'm not sure about the `Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)` part:

```
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shifts_2 | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,index_shifts_on_employee_id,index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at,index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    2 |    11.11 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shifts   | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,index_shifts_on_employee_id,index_sm_shifts_on_employee_id_and_start_at_and_end_at,index_sm_employee_id_id_start_end | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    2 |     2.50 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
```

How can I improve this to avoid scanning so many rows?

I need to identify what shifts are in conflict so users can delete them, that's why I need to return the IDs.

A person can have multiple shifts in a single day: A shift 08:00-16:00 should create a conflict with another at 09:00-17:00, but not with one at 16:00-17:00. I've updated a paragraph above explaining this.

Comment: Surely you just need to count the number of occurances per day per employee and if greater than 1 then you are interested.

Comment: BTW sample data and desired output as text would be useful.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've added a note, but I need to return the IDs of the shifts in conflict

Comment: @nnichols I cannot assume they start on the same date. We can assume I only want conflicts between shift IDs listen in the `IN()` clause, yes.

Comment: @nnichols I confirm I only need to know if any of them conflict with each other (1 with 2, 1 with 3, or 2 with 3). But I've seen the list of IDs grow to ~6k IDs in some cases

Comment: @nnichols I've added the EXPLAIN for the query. The variation you ask for has the same results, but `filtered = 0.41` (instead of 1.11) in the 2nd section

Comment: @nnichols done, it seems to perform much better but I'm scared about sending the ID list twice considering it might get quite long...

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this sort of time-range-overlap query logic says that it's good if each table or self-joined table instance has constant date range predicates. Think of them as bounding dates.

```sql
SELECT shifts.id 
  FROM shifts 
 INNER JOIN shifts shifts_2
           ON shifts_2.employee_id = shifts.employee_id 
          AND shifts_2.start_at < '2023-03-01 00:00:00' 
          AND shifts_2.start_at < shifts.end_at 
          AND shifts_2.end_at > '2023-01-31 23:59:00' 
          AND shifts_2.end_at > shifts.start_at 
          AND shifts_2.id != shifts.id 
 WHERE shifts.start_at >= '2023-01-31'   -- begin date range bound
   AND shifts.start_at < '2023-03-02'    -- end data range bound
   AND shifts.id IN (a, very, long, list, of, integers);
```

I'm not confident I understand your business logic, so the date-range boxes I propose might not be correct. The point remains, though: if you can use constant DATETIME constants (instead of comparing DATETIMEs in various columns) you'll likely have a query-performance win.

The proposal I made will probably benefit from an index on `(id, start_at)`.

MySQL, especially older versions, doesn't do a great job optimizing `id IN (a, very, long, list, of, integers)`. If you can rework your code to create a one-column temporary table with a primary key, then populate the temp table with your list, then join it, you may get an even bigger performance boost.

All that being said, 10 seconds isn't absurdly slow for this kind of query.